# Change class after hovering for a second over svg polygon

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, hover

I have a SVG polygon displayed, what I want to do is:

When mouse is hovered over the object, wait for one second and then change the class.

If user hovers out, before one second nothing happens.

What I would like to achieve is something like http://codepen.io/jdsteinbach/pen/CsypF but the svg element must only glow after a second.

What I have so far is:

```js
 $("#firstObject").stop().hover(
   function() { //hovered in
     //delay it and add new class
     console.log("hovered in");

     setTimeout(function() {
       console.log("hovered in in");

       $("#firstObject").attr("class", "SVGOverVideo1 hoveredObject");
     }, 1000);
   }, function() { //hovered out
     //remove class
     $("#firstObject").attr("class", "SVGOverVideo1");
     console.log("hovered out");

   }
 );
```

```css
.SVGOverVideo1 {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: purple;
  stroke-width: 2;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
}
.hoveredObject {
  border: double;
  border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<svg class="SVGOverVideo" id="objectsOverVideoContainer">
  <polygon id="firstObject" class="SVGOverVideo1" points="200,10 250,190 160,210"></polygon>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with css only using transition with delay:

```
transition: stroke 0.01s 1s;
```

The 1s delays the actual transition, and the actual transition time is so small to that no actual transition occurs.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.SVGOverVideo1 {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: purple;
  stroke-width: 2;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
}
.SVGOverVideo1:hover {
  stroke: white;
  transition: stroke 0.001s 1s;
}
```

```html
<svg class="SVGOverVideo" id="objectsOverVideoContainer">
  <polygon id="firstObject" class="SVGOverVideo1" points="200,10 250,190 160,210"></polygon>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.    
</svg>
```